# I have an issue with posting the apk in Google Developer Console?

Tags: android, google-play, google-developers-console

I made an app & then created an APK, generated a signed APK (I was using AndroidStudio 3.0).

I tried to post it, but I had this issue: "You must use a different package name because "com.example" is restricted." I searched on youtube then I solved this issue.

Now I have another issue when I publish my APK to Google Developer Console. The APK is signed I don't know why this doesn't work....

The error is: `"You uploaded an APK signed with a certificate that is not yet valid. You must sign the APK file with a certificate that is valid"`

Comment: Is it first uploaded version of your app? Have you uploaded any apk's for this app before?

Comment: Was your package named exactly "com.example"? Or maybe you just don't want to post it here?

Comment: yes is my first version of app. My first app!

Comment: Hmm... could you provide some more details? When I was uploading my first APK everything was ok by the first time. I was using AndroidStudio builtin certificate system. How did you create your certificate?

Answer (score 0):

You should read the whole of the article on "[Manage your app signing keys](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423)" then maybe re-ask the question when you understand it a little better.

Every app on android is signed. Google will do the signing for you if you opt-in to Google Play App Signing (you should) but you still need to sign your app with an upload key so that Google knows it comes from you, and not some malicious attacker who has taken over your account.

This upload key can be replaced by the Play Console support team, but you should only need to do this in an emergency. Until then you should generate an upload certificate, sign your app with it, and keep the certificate safe.

All the instructions for how to generate an upload key, and sign your app with it are in the article linked above.